# Android GridView. Как изменить цвет или размер текста в отдельной ячейке

Tags: android, gridview

В таблице верхняя строка представляет загаловок. А нижняя строка суммиует столбцы таблицы.
Адаптер самый примитивный. 
`itemsArray` это все содержимое таблицы (массив String[]). `tableitem` и `tvTextt`это расстановка и TextView.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tableitem, R.id.tvTextt, itemsArray);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
gridView.setNumColumns(3);
```

Как сделать, чтобы первые и последние 3 элемента таблицы (ячейки заголовка и нижней строки) покрасились в какой-то другой цвет, а размер текста поменялся (чтобы таблица не выглядела монотонной)?

Answer (score 1):

Сделай свой адаптер наследуясь хочешь от `ArrayAdapter` прям в методе `getView()` определяй свои элементы и крась в любой цвет.